# Missing references problem with Prism 7.1 upgrade

Tags: prism

Recently wanted to migrate my WPF Prism app to 7.1 and in doing so I get missing references errors with respect to Unity.Abstractions.

Upgraded Prism nuget packages to Prism7.1 as seen in the packages.config below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Prism.Core" version="7.1.0.431" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Prism.Unity" version="7.1.0.431" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Prism.Wpf" version="7.1.0.431" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Unity.Container" version="5.9.4" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

App.xaml code as below:

```
<prism:PrismApplication x:Class="WPFPrismDemoApp.App"
                x:ClassModifier="internal" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

App.xaml.cs code as below:

```
 public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell(Window shell)
        {
            base.InitializeShell(shell);
            Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
            var container= Container.GetContainer();
        }
```

In doing this when I try to access the unity container  through Container.GetContainer, I get the following exception:
The type 'IUnityContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add reference to assembly 'Unity.Abstractions, Version 3.3.1.0'.
I don't understand when I upgraded the WPF.Unity nuget package to latest available it automatically upgraded Unity.Abstractions to 4.0.3.0.

Anybody having idea how to get pass it.

Answer (score 3):

The package Unity.Container version 5.8.x references Unity.Abstractions version 3.3.1, while newer versions reference version 4.0.3. This breaks the backwards compatibility with Bootstrapper in Prism. If you want to use newer versions you are required to use the new PrismAplication class. Kind of sad.

Comment: However, you can use Prism 7.1 with Unity.Container version 5.8.13, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrade your Unity to version 5.8.x.
I think version 5.9.x has a different set of DLLs.